# Draw a cross in a position and how node rotation works

Tags: ios, math, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm playing with spriteKit to create a little game and I'm getting blocked trying to draw a cross (like and X) at a point where i've touched the screen. As i want to draw an X I thought in rotate two rectangles, one Pi/4 and the other one -Pi/4.

I've the following code, i've been playing with node position adding 10 or 20px on both axis. But I cannot understand how the rects intersect on their center for create a cross (like an X).

That's the code I have :

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        guard let touch = touches.first
            else
        {
            return
        }

    let location = touch.location(in: self)

    let touchedNode = nodes(at: location)
    _ = atPoint(location).name

    print("Posición touch: \(touchedNode)")

    // Draw the cross in the touched point
    let redSprite1 = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 40))
    redSprite1.fillColor = .green
    redSprite1.position = CGPoint(x: location.x - 10.0, y: location.y)
    redSprite1.zRotation = CGFloat(-Pi/4)
    addChild(redSprite1)
//      2
        let redSprite2 = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 40))
        redSprite2.fillColor = .red
        redSprite2.position = CGPoint(x: location.x + 10.0, y: location.y)
        redSprite2.zRotation = CGFloat(Pi/4)
        addChild(redSprite2)
    }
```

I've noted that the rotation is made not from the center of the shape but in their bottom.
Is there any option to rotate a shape or tile from their center ?

Comment: Hi can you add your overide of touchesBegan and touchesMoved.

Comment: Method touchesBegan added, touchedMoved is not yet defined.

Comment: Hi again OK so just to be clear you want a red horizontal line, to intersect with a green vertical line. Making a cross at the location you press/tap on a 

Comment: No, I want a cross like an X. That's why I rotate one rectangle Pi/4 and the other -Pi/4. Sorry I haven't explained it so well in the original question.

Comment: Your SKShapeNode(rect:) is specifying a rectangle with corner at the node's origin (0,0).  If you want the rectangle centered on the node's origin, use SKShapeNode(rectOf:) and specify just the width and height. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshapenode/1520147-init

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect. I've posted my code with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @bg2b for the solution.

Looking to the apple doc linked on @bg2b answer and applied give the following code.

```
// 1
let redSprite1 = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 40.0))
redSprite1.fillColor = .green
redSprite1.position = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
redSprite1.zRotation = CGFloat(-Pi/4)
redSprite1.name = "cruz1"
addChild(redSprite1)
// 2
let redSprite2 = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 40.0))
redSprite2.fillColor = .red
redSprite2.position = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
redSprite2.zRotation = CGFloat(Pi/4)
redSprite2.name = "cruz2"
addChild(redSprite2)
```